# What is this equation $f^e = f^a - \nabla U$?

Tags: classical-mechanics, forces, terminology, potential-energy

Recently in a mechanics class my prof scribbled down something looked like $$f^e = f^a - \nabla U.$$

Where he claimed $f^e$ is the external force on an object, $f^a$ is the applied force on the object, $U$ is some potential field.

I don't recognize this equation from any past lectures, can someone provide a reference on where this equation might have shown up?

Comment: $- \Delta U$ is the force due to the potential the object is in. The external force is the sum of the force due to the potential and any applied force.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what he's saying is that

$$F_{net} = F_{nc} + \nabla U,$$

which is pretty standard. $f^a$ is your net force, which is the sum of your conservative and nonconservative forces. Conservative forces can be written as the gradient of some potential, which is where you get your $\nabla U$ from. $f^e,$ then, are your nonconservative forces.